# Confirmation dialog in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am having trouble with code for a confirmation dialog in MIPS:

```
.data
Welcome1:.asciiz  "\n Hello! you are about to play the mastermind guessing and logic game,Bulls & Cows!\n The Computer will generate a secret numbermade of 4 unique integer number.You have to guess the number!\n Using the number of Bulls and Cows you get to find out what the secret number is!\n"
Welcome2: .asciiz "\nEvery digit you enter that is both correct and in the right location is a BULL. When you get 4 BULLS, YOU WIN!\n\nEvery digit you enter that is correct, but not in the right location is a COW!\n"
confirm: .asciiz "\n Select \nYES - if you are ready to guess \n NO - to see the rules again \n Cancel - to exit the Game\n"
.text
main:jal welcome
welcome:
la  $a0,Welcome1
li $a1,1
li $v0, 55
syscall

la,$a0,Welcome2
li $v0,55
syscall

la $a0,confirm
li $v0,50

syscall


Exit:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Hi @user3341473, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you give more details about the problems you're having with your code? What do you expect it to do, and what is happening instead?

Comment: i am looking for a confirm dialog where it has options "yes" or "No" to move further with the program

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you've got a bit more work to do to get the game working, but I've been able to get a skeleton framework going [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data

Welcome1:
    .ascii  "\n Hello! you are about to play the mastermind"
    .ascii  " guessing and logic game,Bulls & Cows!\n"
    .ascii  "The Computer will generate a secret number made of 4 unique"
    .ascii  " integer numbers. You have to guess the number!\n"
    .ascii  "Using the number of Bulls and Cows you get to find out what"
    .asciiz " the secret number is!\n"

Welcome2:
    .ascii  "\nEvery digit you enter that is both correct and in the right"
    .ascii  " location is a BULL. When you get 4 BULLS, YOU WIN!\n\n"
    .ascii  "Every digit you enter that is correct, but not in the right"
    .asciiz " location is a COW!\n"

confirm:
    .ascii  "\n Select \n"
    .ascii  "YES - if you are ready to guess\n"
    .ascii  "NO - to see the rules again\n"
    .asciiz "Cancel - to exit the Game\n"

msg_asknum:
    .asciiz "\nEnter your game choice\n"

    .text

main:

    # show intro and rules
main_welcome:
    la      $a0,Welcome1
    li      $a1,1
    li      $v0,55
    syscall

    la      $a0,Welcome2
    li      $v0,55
    syscall

    # ask user to select an action (i.e. enter data, reread rules, exit program)
main_confirm:
    la      $a0,confirm
    li      $v0,50
    syscall

    # the return is in a0: 0=yes, 1=no, 2=cancel
    beq     $a0,0,main_asknum
    beq     $a0,2,main_exit
    b       main_welcome

    # ask user for the next game input
    # NOTE: this is a prompt for an integer number
main_asknum:
    li      $v0,51
    la      $a0,msg_asknum
    syscall

    beq     $a1,-1,main_asknum      # syntax error
    beq     $a1,-2,main_confirm     # cancel
    beq     $a1,-3,main_asknum      # ok, but no data

    jal     do_something            # do something with the number in a0 ...

    j       main_asknum

main_exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# do_something -- process user's input
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- number the user entered
do_something:
    jr      $ra                     # return
```